# how to override list permission with django-rules

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rules

I installed [django-rules](https://github.com/dfunckt/django-rules) to my project to define rules for my actions. The list function hast no permission setting per default so you have to add them to the `permission_type_map` as written [here](https://github.com/dfunckt/django-rules/blob/2b79375a8ca2f4a2ded97feba0411f837ae7f80b/rules/contrib/rest_framework.py#L13) but without an effect. For the other actions i am able to change the behavior if i set it to `is_superuser` or something else.

```
from django.db import models

import rules
from rules.contrib.models import RulesModel
from rules.contrib.rest_framework import AutoPermissionViewSetMixin

from base.models import BaseModel


class Company(RulesModel, BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    permission_type_map = {
        **AutoPermissionViewSetMixin.permission_type_map,
        "list": "all",
    }

    class Meta:
        rules_permissions = {
            # TODO: rules need to be defined
            "add": rules.always_allow,
            "view": rules.always_allow,
            "delete": rules.always_allow,
            "change": rules.always_allow,
            "all": rules.is_superuser
        }
```

What do i miss here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to django-rules, but from what I can see in the [docs](https://github.com/dfunckt/django-rules#permissions-in-django-rest-framework) you can only extend/change `permission_type_map` when using or subclassing `AutoPermissionViewSetMixin`. Try defining the `permission_type_map` dict in your ViewSet class instead:

```py
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rules.contrib.rest_framework import AutoPermissionViewSetMixin

class MyViewSet(AutoPermissionViewSetMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    permission_type_map = {
        **AutoPermissionViewSetMixin.permission_type_map,
        "list": "all",
    }
```